# VBA : Number format = String Variable + "#,##0"

Tags: vba

Very basic question - somehow can't solve this :-(

Can you please help me to set the number format on a cell to be a combination of a string variable and this number format : "#,##0"?

The objective is to have results appear as EUR #,##0 (if string variable = EUR) or GBP #,##0 (if string variable = GBP) etc.

So far, this is how I was trying to code it:

Dim Currency As String
Set Currency = "EUR"
Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = Currency & " #,##0"

Thank you in advance for your help!

Kind regards,
Claudia

Comment: Try `Dim Currency As String: Currency = "EUR": Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = """" & Currency & """" & " #,##0"` Here `""""` or (Crh(34) which is the same) may be replaced with a constant to clarify the code, i.e. `Const quote = """" :  ... .NumberFormat = quote & currency & quote & ...`

Comment: Wow you solved it! Incredible :-) You cannot imagine how much time I had spent trying to resolve this. Thank you so much :-)!!!!!!!!!!!